# What does the $this->hasData() evaluate and do?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, model

I've seen at several sites having the method `$this->hasData('test');` in their **Block** classes (not template files).

As an example, here's an extract of a method in a Block class from a tutorial [site](https://aionhill.com/magento-2-module-development-part1):

```
public function getTestModel()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('test')) {
        if ($this->getTestId()) {
            /** @var \Aion\Test\Model\Test $test */
            $test = $this->testFactory->create();
            $test->load($this->getTestId());
        } else {
            $test = $this->test;
        }
        $this->setData('test', $test);
    }
    return $this->getData('test');
}
```

I've searched around for this method, but I can't exactly figure out what this function does. Why would I want to store `$test` through `$this->setData('test', $test);`? I could just store it in a class variable like `$this->tmpTest = $test` and return the class variable, couldn't I?

Looking up the Magento source, this is the comment docs of this method in `DataObject.php`:

```
/**
 * If $key is empty, checks whether there's any data in the object
 * Otherwise checks if the specified attribute is set.
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @return bool
 */
```

But what's `$key` and what attribute is this referring to?

What am I actually checking with the `hasData()` method? The example I saw took in the word `test` as its parameter but I have no idea what the word "test" relates to.

What is that parameter the `$this->hasData()` method actually takes in?

Why would I even want to use this method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

every class that extends the `DataObject` class contains a member called `_data`.
From here you can get the values using `$this->getData('key_here')`.
That will return `_data['key_here']`.
The `hasData` method checks if that key is set.
For example `$this->hasData('test')` is an equivalent for `array_key_exists('test', $this->_data)`.
[Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DataObject.php#L230) is where the method is defined.

If your model is a flat table model (all values are kept in a single table) the key should be one of the column names.
For example when having a cms page model, `$this->hasData('identifier')` will check if the page identifier is set.
If the model is an EAV model, the key should be one of the entity attributes.
For example for products, `$this->hasData('name')` will check if the product name is set.

But, in general you can set anything to the `_data` member on any model using `$this->setData('some_key', 'some_value')`.
In this case, the key can be any string.
Then you can check if the data for a certain key is set with `$this->hasData('some_key');`

Comment: Is the key any arbitrary string? Or does this "key" relate to any thing such as id or model names, etc in my code?

Comment: See my update to the answer.

Comment: So, let's say I have a flat table model. And in my table, I have a column called "test_id". When I call `$this->hasData('test_id')`, I should be getting a `true` value from it?

Comment: yes. If that value is set you get true out of it.

Comment: umm... sorry, the part u said "if that value is set..." got me stumble a bit. I actually have a `test_id` column in my table but when I call `$this->hasData('test_id')`, I get a false value. Is there something else I have to call to get all the table values set so that when I call `hasData('test_id')` will return me a true value? Sorry if I'm sounding silly; I'm very new to magento.

Comment: It return false because your column(test_id) doesn't contain any value. If its contain any value then it return true @xenon

Comment: @KeyurShah I do have rows in my table that have values under the column `test_id`. umm.. Am I understanding something wrong here?

Comment: In case I wasn't clear that `$this->hasData()` is calling from the Block class and *not* from a template file, I've updated my question with an example code.